# Diferença na declaração do Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Estou começando a trabalhar com o Socket.io no Node.js, a dúvida por enquanto segue simples.
Usando meu exemplo abaixo.
Qual a diferença em usar socket.emit() e chat.emit()? 
PS:*Espero que não tenha erro de sintaxe kkk.

```js
var chat = io.of('/chat')
             .on('connection', function (socket) {
                 socket.emit('testOne', {
                    data: 'data'
                 });
                 chat.emit('testTwo', {
                    data2: 'data2'
                 });
             });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`socket.emit` irá emitir o evento para este socket específico, no caso algum cliente que está conectado e representa o socket.

Em `chat.emit` o evento é emitido para todos os clientes que estão conectados no namespace `/chat` (que é criado em `io.of('/chat')`).